# Row Value Change after Refresh

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

When I Click on Confirmed Button the Value in changing on phpMyAdmin but on my Admin it is changing after Refreshing the page

here is a Code

```
 <input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" name="order_id_value">
<input type="submit" class="btn-conf" name="u_confirmed" value="Confirmed"><br>
<input type="submit" name="u_dispatch" class="btn-dispatch" value="Dispatch"><br>
<input type="submit" name="u_spam" class="btn-spam center" value="Spam"><br>
<input type="submit" name="u_delete" class="btn-delete" value="Delete">
        <?php 
if (isset($_POST['u_confirmed'])) {
$iddd    = $_POST["order_id_value"];
/* $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wprf_quickorder WHERE order_id = %d",$iddd)); */
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wprf_quickorder SET status = 'Confirmed' WHERE order_id = %d",$iddd) );
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: what exactly need to be changed in this form after it been sent?

Comment: The value is updating on Database (phpmyadmin) but its not updating in the dashboard until I Refresh it

Comment: try to move php code above the html.

Comment: Solved Thanks alot Bro :)